# Blu-ray Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, blu-ray

I would like to play Blu-ray disc that I purchased on my Windows 7 computer, using Windows Media Player.

I would prefer a method to make this happen with Windows Media Player and not another program such as VLC.

Comment: @StevenPenny - Media Player does not support Blu-ray media, it has no support for it, there are many reasons for this fact.  The main reason is the license costs for support and the DRM connected to this type of media.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Microsoft [MPEG and DVD video: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/MPEG-and-DVD-video-frequently-asked-questions)

> **Can I play a Blu‑ray Disc?**
>
> To play a Blu‑ray Disc, you need to use a
> non-Microsoft program that supports Blu‑ray playback and a device
> capable of reading Blu‑ray Discs.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Cyberlink products will play them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options (in 2018):

- ArcSoft TotalMedia Theatre
- [Corel WinDVD](https://www.windvdpro.com/en/)
- [Cyberlink PowerDVD](https://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd-ultra/features_en_EU.html) <--------- recommended
- [DVDFab Player](https://www.dvdfab.cn/media-player.htm)
- [Kodi](http://www.kodi.tv) (from v18 - not out yet)
- Nero Blu-ray Player
- [VideoLAN VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Note that you will also need to have [Java](https://www.java.com/en/) installed, in a bit version that matches the bit version of the software media player you choose. E.g. 32bit VLC => 32bit Java. (The way to get a certain bit version of Java, is to visit www.java.com with a browser in that bit-version. E.g. visit with a 64bit browser if you wish to get 64bit Java (because you've downloaded a 64bit software media player)).

Java is needed to run the menus on most Blu-rays.

All of the above players are available for Windows. If you're a Linux user, your options are currently limited to Kodi v18 and VLC 3.0.1. If you're a Mac user, check out [MacGo Blu-ray Player](https://www.macblurayplayer.com/).

You will of course also need to buy an actually Blu-ray Disc drive for your PC. But all the players above can also play a Blu-ray from harddisk or USB, either in the form of an ISO file.